# Batch update with aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, database, mongodb, backend

I have a list of pipeline operations and would like to use the result to update on the collection by _id.

Right now I have something like this in java:

```
Cursor cursor = getCollection().aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        pipeline1,
                        pipline2,
                        ...
                ), AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(true).batchSize(1000).build()
        );
```

how would I make it do the update as well without iterating through the cursor as it would co through my java service and update one by one.
How would I something like:

```
[collection].updateMany(
    {},
    [
      pipeline1,
      pipeline2
    ]
)
```

instead? The aggregation result is very large (hundreds of thousands) so updating one by one isn't an option.

If there's some better way to do this please share too.

Comment: Yes $out does work but directly updating the existing collection would be better since the data needs to be permanently stored, updating the result of $out into the existing collection would achieve the same result I guess but that would be an additional step.

Comment: $merge is the ideal one. Yes, extra step required

Comment: @Gibbs thanks that works exactly like the update would and I don't need to through Java.

Comment: It doesn't work on the same collection so I still have to use $out first, I'm curious if updateMany with aggregation pipeline does the same thing underneath

Comment: updateMany and aggregation framework are two different things.